# Master theorem in which k is rational

Tags: algorithms

I've been looking at my algorithms and complexity course's suggested exercises for master theorem and I the only one I can't seem to solve is a case in which k is rational. I managed to prove that master theorem is applicable, but I don't know how to go about using it. The function in question is

```
T(n) = 3T(n/9) + Θ(n^(7/6))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can apply the Master theorem as normal with $a = 3$, $b = 9$ and $f(n) = n^{7/6}$. Notice that $n^{7/6} = \Omega(n^{\log_b a + \epsilon}) = \Omega(n^{1/2 + \epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ (pick one). Checking the regularity condition:

$$
af(n/b) = 3\left(\frac{n}{9}\right)^{7/6} = \frac{3}{9^{7/6}} n^{7/6} \leq kn^{7/6}
$$

for

$$
k = \frac{3}{9^{7/6}} < 1,
$$

so the regularity condition holds. Applying case 3, we arrive at $T(n) = \Theta(n^{7/6})$.

Comment: Great answer, just a quick follow-up question, ϵ can be a fraction, right?

Comment: @JustACuriousMind Yes, $\epsilon$ can be any real number greater than zero.